# How to move to down of the page using button in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add button on top of the page and one form at the bottom when I click on the button it should go down at the form location on same page. I am don't know how I can do that.

here is my code for button

```html
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2">
                     <p style="padding:40px;"></p>
                <button class="btn btn-block btn-warning">Reserve Table</button>
                </div>
```

Here is my code of form

```html
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
                <div class="form-vertical" role="form">
                      <p style="padding:10px;"></p>
                    <h3>Table Reservation</h3>
             </div>
        </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-9">
                <div class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                      <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Number" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Number of people</label>  
                   <label class="radio-inline">
                       <input type="radio" name="optradio">1
                    </label>
                    <label class="radio-inline">
                        <input type="radio" name="optradio">2
                    </label>
                <label class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" name="optradio">3
                </label>
                           <label class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" name="optradio">4
                </label>
                           <label class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" name="optradio">5
                </label>
                           <label class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" name="optradio">6
                </label>
                    </div>
                <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                 <label for="Date-time" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Date &amp; Time</label>  
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
          
                <input type="text" class="form-control pull-left" name="Date-time" placeholder="date">
                          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar form-control-feedback"></i>
                        </div>
                        
                     <div class="form-group  has-feedback">
                 
                              <div class="col-sm-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="time">
                          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time form-control-feedback"></i>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
  Please <strong ><a href="tel:81343444" style="color:black">call</a></strong> for bookinng of more than 6 people.
</div>
                    </div>
             </div>
```

please tell me how to do this??

Comment: I generally don't recommend w3schools but this is a good example: http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_links_bookmark Also please use Google, you should be able to find answer very quickly.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for this much quick response. Ya I tried google but may be I was not able to give proper query on that. Anyway thanks a ton

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hello @lomesh shah this is easy.

### Step 1

First give that form an id like

```
<form id="testform"> rest of the code goes here </form>
```

### Step 2

You have to use anchor tag instead of the button but by using bootstrap's btn classes over it you can give it a button apperance and then use id of the form inside the href, click which will take you down to the form. See code below

```
<a href="#testform" class="btn btn-block btn-warning">Go to form</a>
```

Confusion ? Hit me back :) I will respond

Answer (score 1):

give the form id 
then use this

```
              <a href="#id" ><button   type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg">Reserve Table</button></a>
```